# why jquery alert message not working accurately inside foreach loop?

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp

When dropdown list box will be blank, I am trying to view message alert box by jquery in foreach loop but not working what can I do?

**my cakephp code is below:**

```
 <?php
                foreach ($data['customer'] as $index => $d):
                    $customer = $d;
                    $package = array();
                    if (count($data['package']) > 0) {
                        $package = $data['package'][$index];
                    }
                    ?>
                    <tr class="odd gradeX">

                        <td><?php echo $customer['first_name'] . ' ' . $customer['middle_name'] . ' ' . $customer['last_name']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <ul>
                                <li>Cell:<?php echo $customer['cell']; ?></li>
                                <li>Address:<?php echo $customer['address'] ?></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php if (count($package) > 0): ?>
                                <ul>
                                    <li> Package Name: <?php echo $package['name']; ?></li>
                                    <li> Month: <?php echo $package['duration']; ?></li>
                                    <li> Charge: <?php echo $package['charge']; ?></li>
                                </ul>
                                <?php
                            endif;
                            ?>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->create('PackageCustomer', array(
                                'inputDefaults' => array(
                                    'label' => false,
                                    'div' => false
                                ),
                                'id' => 'form_sample_3',
                                'class' => 'form-horizontal',
                                'novalidate' => 'novalidate',
                                'url' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'changeservice')
                                    )
                            );
                            ?>

                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('id', array(
                                'type' => 'hidden',
                                'value' => $customer['id']
                                    )
                            );
                            ?>
                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->input('status', array(
                                'type' => 'select',
                                'id' => 'ddlist',
                                'options' => Array('ticket' => 'Generate Ticket', 'payment' => 'Customer  Information', 'history' => 'Ticket History'),
                                'empty' => 'Select Action',
                                'class' => 'form-control form-filter input-sm',
                                    )
                            );
                            ?>
                            <br>
                            <?php
                            echo $this->Form->button(
                                    'Go', array('class' => 'btn blue', 'id' => 'btnddlist', 'title' => 'Do this selected action', 'type' => 'submit')
                            );
                            ?>

                            <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                endforeach;
                ?>
```

**my jquery code is:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
$("#btnddlist").click(function () {
    var ddlist = $("#ddlist");
    if (ddlist.val() == "") {
        //If the "Please Select" option is selected display error.
        alert("Please select a list data!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

});

By this code when I click first record button code working but others record button when I click not view alert box message!

Comment: Regarding DOM concept you can have only one element with certain ID within entire DOM object (your page). So try to find another way of notation and object access. In other words is not acceptable to have more than one HTML element with `#btnddlist` or `#ddlist` IDs.

Answer (score 1):

that's because it is programmed to only respond to the first `option`:

```
if (ddlist.val() == "") {
    //If the "Please Select" option is selected display error.
    alert("Please select a list data!");
    return false;
}
```

if you want to display your message (alert) on every `option` (for whatever reason, you can just remove the `if` condition of the above code, so you got only:

```
//changed: always displays message now.
alert("You selected something in the list!");
return false;
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks, I use your concept but not working! requirement is when don't select any list data in drop down list box then alert box will be view.